# Wordpress и Jquery. Одна кнопка для элементов

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Есть такая дилемма. Пытаюсь создать под себя плагин карусели для WordPress. Через JQuery буду динамически добавлять вот такие блоки (каждый блок - это отдельный слайдер).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу понять как при нажатии на кнопку "добавить слайд" добавлять изображение именно в тот блок, внутри которого находится сама кнопка??? ID у них одинаковый.

Структура блока вот такая

```
<div class="cont-slider">

   <p><a href="#" id="add-slide" class="page-title-action">Добавить слайд</a></p>

   <span class="alx-slider-name"> <input type="text" class="core" name="alx_sliders"> </span><!-- Сюда попадают имя нового слайдера -->

   <textarea type="hidden" name="alx_sliders" class="area-hidden" cols="50" rows="3"></textarea>

       <div class="sortable">

                    <!-- Сюда попадают изображения добавленные в слайдер -->


        </div> <!-- end sortable -->
 </div>
```

Вот код кнопки

```
//  Выводит медиа-загрузчик WP для добавления слайда
        $('#add-slide').live('click',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var image = wp.media({ 
            title: 'Загрузка изображения',
            library: {type: 'image'},
            multiple: false
        }).open()
        .on('select', function(e){
            var uploaded_image = image.state().get('selection').first();
            console.log(uploaded_image);
            var image_url = uploaded_image.toJSON().url;
            var alt = uploaded_image.toJSON().alt;
            var aUrl = uploaded_image.toJSON().caption;
            var element = ' <img src="' + image_url +'" class="alx-inner-img img-responsive" alt="' + alt +'"> ';
            //вставляем элемент после блока .sortable
            $('.sortable').first().prepend(element);

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем сам нашел ответ, методом научного тыка и документации JQuery. Если кому интересно. Кнопку добавить слайд я вынес из "p", а в JQuery написал так в переменную **thisK** получаем текущий элемент то есть кнопку. Потом просто пишем **thisK.next().next().next().prepend(element);** и вставляем нужную нам картинку через нужное количество элементов. И все заработало.

```
//  Выводит медиа-загрузчик WP для добавления слайда
    $('.add-slide').live('click',function(e) {
      var  thisK = $(this);
    e.preventDefault();
    var image = wp.media({ 
        title: 'Загрузка изображения',
        library: {type: 'image'},
        multiple: false
    }).open()
    .on('select', function(e){
        var uploaded_image = image.state().get('selection').first();
        console.log(uploaded_image);
        var image_url = uploaded_image.toJSON().url;
        var alt = uploaded_image.toJSON().alt;
        var aUrl = uploaded_image.toJSON().caption;
        var element = ' <img src="' + image_url +'" class="alx-inner-img img-responsive" alt="' + alt +'"> ';

        thisK.next().next().next().prepend(element);
    });
});
```